# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HourlyWorker'

Tags: python

I keep getting an AttributeError: and I can't figure it out. Would appreciate any assistance.

```
import worker

def main():
    #Create a list to store employee and volunteer objects
    workers = make_list()

    #Display the objects in the list
    print ('\n\nHere are the workers, their ID numbers, city of residence, shift, and pay.')
    print ('--------------------------------------------------------------')

    display_list(workers)

def make_list():
    #Create an empty list
    worker_list = []

    #Create a volunteer object
    print ('Create a volunteer worker object:')
    name = input('\nWhat is the employee name? ')
    id_number = input("What is the employee's number? ")
    city = input("What is the employee's city? ")
    volunteerworker = worker.Person(name, id_number, city)
    worker_list.append(volunteerworker)

    #Create 3 hourly worker objects
    print ('Create 3 hourly worker objects:')
    for hourlyworkers in range(1,4):
        name = input('\nWhat is the employee number ' + str(hourlyworkers + 1) + "'s name? ")
        id_number = input("What is the employee's number? ")
        city = input("What is the employee's city? ")
        shift = input("What is the employee's shift? ")
        #validate the shift entered is 1, 2, or 3
        while shift != '1' and shift != '2' and shift != '3':
            print( 'ERROR: the shift can only be 1, 2, or 3.')
            shift = input('Please enter the correct shift: ')

        pay_rate = float(input("What is the employee's hourly pay rate? "))
        hourlyworker = worker.HourlyWorker(name, id_number, city, shift, pay_rate)
        worker_list.append(hourlyworker)

    #create a salary worker object
    print ('Create a volunteer worker object')
    name = input("\nWhat is the salaried employee's name? ")
    id_number = input("What is the employee's number? ")
    city = input("WHat is the employee's city? ")
    pay_rate = float(input("What is the employee's annual salary? "))
    salaryworker = worker.SalaryWorker(name, id_number, city, pay_rate)
    worker_list.append(salaryworker)

    #append invalid object to list
    worker_list.append('\nThis is an invalid object')

    return worker_list

#This function accpets an object as an argument, and calls its show_employee
#and show_pay methods

def display_list(worker_list):
    for person in worker_list:
        if isinstance(person, worker.Person):
            person.show_employee()
            person.show_pay()
            print()
        else:
            print('That is not a valid employee type!')

main()
```

Here is the code for worker.py class Person and class HourlyWorker(Person):

```
PREMIUM2 = .05
PREMIUM3 = .10
PAY_PERIODS = 26

class Person:

    #The __init__ method initialized the attributes
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, city):
        self.__name = name
        self.__id_number = id_number
        self.__city = city

    #This method accepts an argument for the person's name
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    #This method accepts an argument for the person's ID number
    def set_id_number(self, id_number):
        self.__id_number = id_number

    #This method accepts an argument for the person's city of residence
    def set_city(self, city):
        self.__city = city

    #This method returns the employee's name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    #This method returns the employee's number
    def get_id_number(self):
        return self.__id_number

    #This method returns the employee's city of residence
    def get_city(self):
        return self.__city

    #This method displays a message indicating the employee's name, ID, and city of residence
    def show_employee(self):
        print ('Employee name is', self.__name)
        print ('Employee number is', self.__id_number)
        print ('Employee city is', self.__city)

    #This method displays a message about the volunteer's pay status
    def show_pay(self):
        print()
        print ('This person is an unpaid volunteer.')
        print()

class Hourlyworker(Person):

    #This method calls the superclass's init method and initializes shift and
    #pay rate attributes
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, city, shift, pay_rate):
        Person.__init__(self, name, id_number, city)
        self.__shift = shift
        self.pay_rate = pay_rate

    #This method calculates and displays the hourly and premium pay rate of a 
    #production employee
    def show_pay(self):
        print ('Employee shift is', self.__shift)
        if self.__shift == '1':
            premium_rate = self.__pay_rate
        elif self.__shift == '2':
            premium_rate = (PREMIUM2 * self.__pay_rate) + self.__pay_rate
        else:
            premium_rate = (PREMIUM3 * self.__pay_rate) + self.__pay_rate
        print('Employee hourly premium rate is $', format(premium_rate, '.2f'))

class SalaryWorker(Person):

    #This method calls the superclass's init method and initializes the 
    #pay rate attribute
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, city, pay_rate):
        Person.__init__(self, name, id_number, city)
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate

    #This method displays the annual salary and bi_weekly gross pay for the
    #salaried employee
    def show_pay(self):
        print('Employee annual salary is $', format(self.__pay_rate, '.2f'))
        bi_weekly_pay = float(self.__pay_rate) / PAY_PERIODS
        print('Employee bi-weekly gross pay is $', format(bi_weekly_pay, '.2f'))
```

This is the error I keep getting in Wing IDE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "10.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "10.py", line 15, in <module>
    workers = make_list()
  File "10.py", line 48, in <module>
    hourlyworker = worker.HourlyWorker(name, id_number, city, shift, pay_rate)
builtins.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HourlyWorker'
```

Thanks

Comment: Typo dude! Check your cases...

Comment: shiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed you have implemented a class called `Hourlyworker` and trying to access another class named `HourlyWorker`? When Python says `object has no attribute` it really means it ;)

Hint, just in case: Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Alex don't judge yourself too hard on Sunday evenings ;)